# How to access a method in a deep nested parent [Vue][Vuetify]

Tags: vue.js, components, vuetify.js, parent

I have made a Vue component that has a v-data-table.

Child Component

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <v-data-table>
            <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-icon @click="validation(item)"> mdi-check <v-icon/>
                    <span> Validar movimentação </span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
        name: "ViewDraftTable",
        data() {
            return {
                movimentacoesSalvasHeader: [...]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            validation(item) {
                this.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.validateMov(item)
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in the parent, I have the `validate()` method.
How am I supposed to call this method, without having to navigate inside the nested `$parents`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject), where the parent `provide`s the method, and a deep nested child could `inject` it where needed:

```js
// Parent.vue
export default {
  provide() {
    return {
      validate(item) {
        /* perform validation */
      }
    }
  }
}

// ViewDraftTable.vue
export default {
  inject: {
    validate: {
      default: item => { /* perform default validation */ }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validacao(item) {
      this.validate(item)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at a state management library like [Vuex](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/)

Or use provide/inject

Comment: Thx, I know about Vuex but I guess that this is not the case for use it, because it's a simple method call from the child. I'm thinking about something like just reference the method from parent in the child.